# Cisco switch police bandwidth for IPv4 and IPv6 traffic

Tags: cisco, switching

I am trying to limit the bandwidth of several VLANs on Catalyst 3750X (c3750e-universalk9-mz.152-4.E10.bin) and Nexus 3064PQ (n3000-compact.9.3.9.bin) switches without success...

It is necessary to limit the IPV4 **and** IPV6 flow in the VLAN in order to have a flow of 10Mb for example. Switches are in Layer 2 mode, there is no SVI.

In IPV4 no problem, but it is not possible to add IPV6 ACLs !!!

```
Class-map with match vlanXXX cannot be activated.
```

Is there a solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have to limit IPv4 and IPv6 *each*?  Or is it just 10Mb total BW?

Comment: 10Mb is the total BW for the whole IPV4+IPV6 traffic.

Comment: Could you simply do a `match any` or `class default` and apply it to the VLAN interface?

Comment: I have no VLAN interface (no SVI on the switch).The switches are in access

Comment: I assumed VLANs based on your error message.  But in that case, apply the policy to the interface

Comment: To summarize, I can't add a service policy input with an IPV4 and IPV6 ACL... This do not work :

Comment: `ipv6 access-list V6_ACL_DOWN-10M
 permit ipv6 any 2001:DB8:1234:5678::/64
 deny ipv6 any any
!
ip access-list extended V4_ACL_DOWN-10M
 permit ip any host X.X.X.1
 deny   ip any any
!
class-map match-any LIMIT_DOWN-10M
 match access-group name V4_ACL_DOWN-10M
 match access-group name V6_ACL_DOWN-10M
!
policy-map LIMIT_DOWN
 class LIMIT_DOWN-10M
  police 10000000 1000000 exceed-action drop
!
interface G1/0/1
 service-policy input LIMIT_DOWN
!
`

Comment: Oh. I thought you were policing all traffic. In that case you can’t do what you want. Maybe with a newer OS version

Comment: On the Catalyst 3750-X I have the latest version of IOS... Possible to do this on Catalyst 4900M or 4500-X ??

Comment: "_On the Catalyst 3750-X I have the latest version of IOS.._" No, the last software release for that switch model was nearly five years ago (October 30, 2017), and there have been many IOS versions since then that are not available for that switch, which is EoL. You should upgrade to a current switch model. The current switches are the 9000 series, the 9300 as the closest equitant to the 3750-X